# How to find matrix $A$ if $Adj(A)$ is given

Tags: matrices

How to find matrix $A$ when $adj(A) = ( A_1 A_2 A_3 )$ where $A_1=(1,2,1)' A_2=(3,2,-1)' A_3=(4,-2,4)'$. And $'$ denotes transpose .

I tried by taking $3\times 3$ matrix with $9$ unknown elements and a property that $A.AdjA=AdjA.A=|A|I$. But it is difficult . I want to know the easiest approach. Please help me.

Comment: You know $\det A$ from $\det (\mathrm{adj}(A))=(\det A)^2$, so $A=\det A (\mathrm{adj}(A))^{-1}$. Provided the adjoint is nonsingular.

Answer (score 1):

Since the determinant of the adjoint is not zero, the adjoint and the inverse of $A$ only differ by an obvious multiplicative constant.